# Is there a specific Conditional Probability Function for Image Processing in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, probability-density

I am trying to develop a motion estimation image processing algorithm in MATLAB, and as part of a paper that I am following I need to maximize the conditional probability density function for each frame.

My question is, is there a pdf function in MATLAB specifically for image processing, or should the pdf function in the statistics toolbox work?

I would appreciate any help on this!

Thank you!

Comment: No, you should be able to use the stuff from the Stats toolbox, but bear in mind that the image measurements are discrete while the PDFs from the Stats toolbox are continuous... unless you specifically use a discrete version (Bernoulli for example).  I'm leaving this as a comment because I'm actually not sure if this is the right answer... but intuitively, and from my reasoning... the answer should be yes.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  In fact, I will be using a Rayleigh distribution because I am looking at motion analysis and that seems to be the distribution of choice for this type of work.